# How can I get a RangeList's cell values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a `RangeList` that contains a series of rows from which I want to draw data. For example, I might have the RangeList object defined:

```
const values = sheet.getRangeList(["1:1", "3:3", "5:5"])
```

The `getValues()` function doesn't work on the `RangeList`, is there a built in and faster way to get the values in Google App Scripts?

Comment: Is it different from your previous question? If so how?

Comment: @TheMaster I've updated the question to, hopefully, make it clearer. I'm asking more specifically if there's a built in way to get the values of a `RangeList` without doing it row by row as I did in the other question. It seems peculiar that there's no obvious way to use the RangeList like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Get Values

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Form')
  const values = sh.getRangeList(["1:1", "3:3", "5:5"]).getRanges().map(rg => rg.getValues().flat().filter(e => e)).join(',');
  Logger.log(values);
}
```